# React - cannot access parameter in setState method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to update some state in my app in the below code.

However the `id` doesn't appear to be accessible in the `setRelease` call (the complier also says it `is unused ts 6133`.

Any ideas what I'm missing

```
function progressItemClicked(id: number) {
        if (release) {

            setRelease(prevState => ({
                ...release,
                progress: {
                    ...prevState?.progress,
                    id: true
                }
            }))

        }

}
```

Comment: The `id` argument is not used though. What are you trying to access in the `setRelease` callback other than `release` and `prevState`? It should certainly be accessible anywhere in the `progressItemClicked` function scope.

Comment: I'm trying to use it when I update a property to true `id: true`, e.g. 0: true

Comment: You want `[id]: true`, which is a computed property name.

Comment: try wrap it with bracket `[id]: true`